# How to link the new page once "login" button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I have App.jsx that has a routing and I have a component Login that should point to the next page once it is clicked. My issue is: how can I tell the server that login button is clicked and now it has to go to net page?

App.jsx contains two links: 1. Register 2. Login

This is my App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Login, Register } from "./components/index";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLogginActive: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Add .right by default
    this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
  }

  changeState() {
    const { isLogginActive } = this.state;

    if (isLogginActive) {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("left");
    } else {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("left");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isLogginActive } = this.state;
    const current = isLogginActive ? "Register" : "Login";
    const currentActive = isLogginActive ? "login" : "register";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="login">
          <div className="container" ref={ref => (this.container = ref)}>
            {isLogginActive && (
              <Login containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
            )}
            {!isLogginActive && (
              <Register containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
            )}
          </div>
          <RightSide
            current={current}
            currentActive={currentActive}
            containerRef={ref => (this.rightSide = ref)}
            onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RightSide = props => {
  return (
    <div
      className="right-side"
      ref={props.containerRef}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      <div className="inner-container">
        <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What kind of router you are using ? `BrowserRouter`? Using react router you can change the route path

Answer (score 1):

I think you are currently toggling the components -Login & Register based on variable isLogginActive. So there is no routing currently done in your code.

Routing can be done in a few ways like,
a) using  anchor tag, it will be like a server call so you will see a page reload on click,
b) using react-router-dom package with Link, refer - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start , this will do a client side routing no reload of page.